Mando llamar a mi template, pero me deja la pantalla en blanco en vue.js
Tengo mi proyecto en vue.js 2.5 para esto tengo una tabla la cual le mando los datos y me imprime mi tabla, pero al momento de darle clic al boton de ver (el cual se encuentra en la tabla) este no me manda a un template que tengo personalizado, solamente me quita todo de la pantalla y la deja en blanco, estos son mis metodos.
 //Obetner los datos de la direccion
    getdireccion(idDireccion) {
      let url = this.$store.state.apiUrl + "api/Address/" + idDireccion;
      this.axios.get(url).then(response => {
        this.dataDireccion = response.data;
        this.dataForm.dataItemDirecciones = response.data;
        this.dataForm.dataItemAuxDirecciones = this.clone(this.dataForm.dataItemDirecciones);

      });
    },
loadDataFormDireccion(item) {
      let idDireccion = item.value.id;
      this.getdireccion(idDireccion);
      this.dataForm.eventCatalog = item.accion;
      this.dataForm.eventCatalogBefore = "table";
    },

este es la estructura de mi template
<template v-if="dataForm.eventCatalog == 'readClient'"></template>


y donde esta ese boton?
